# jedis get getting stale data

Tags: java, tomcat, redis, jedis

we have scenario where we are saving updating value for key multiple time .
The value contain set object where data is updated after each operation.

problem is that get method is always returning data which is fetched 1st time and we are only getting updated data on server restart.

We are using jedispool default configuration and tried multiple methods to debug this but i am not making any headway

```
byte[] reply = jedis.get(keyBytes);

 jedis.setex(keyBytes, expiration, valueBytes);
```

this can be silly reason for this error so please help me to progress further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like using same outputstream for various call was causing this issue